# How to store dates before 1970-01-01 in a contract

Tags: solidity

It is recommended to store dates in a uint. Can I use `int` if I want to sore a date before 1970-01-01 (for example a birth date) which is before 1970-01-01? If I use int `int date = now;` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can store whatever you like in your contract and give it whatever meaning you like.

However, `now` returns a `uint` so you'll need to cast it. Try `int date = int(now)`.

Comment: I think that this dude wants to know how to store a date prior to 1970, and then be able to use `now` in conjunction with that. For example, suppose that he has a variable `date` which stores `26/08/1968`. Then he would like to have the expression `now - date` equal 50 years (in seconds). With `now` representing the number of seconds since 1970, this is not possible. I think that this dude is asking how to store dates prior to 1970, in a manner which will allow this type of computation returning the correct answer.

Comment: @goodvibration The original poster specifically asked about using `int` (signed) 
instead of `uint` (unsigned). Using negative numbers for times before 1970 seems perfectly reasonable, and this answer shows how that can be done.

Comment: @goodvibration Maybe I'm being dumb but I think the arithmetic should work fine with negative numbers? eg 40 years - 10 years = 30 years, 40 years - -10 years = 50 years.

Comment: You're not being dumb IMO. And now that I see the dude's problem with `date = now`, your suggestion probably solves it. I haven't used signed integers in Solidity at all, but I guess that there is not going to be any specific problem with `now - date` when `date` is signed. Nevertheless, I think that generally, it may be a little "risky" to mix signed integers into unsigned arithmetic, because one needs to be very careful on every operation thereafter (arithmetic operations as well as bit-wise operations).

Comment: There's no mixing because there's unsigned arithmetic involved. You cast an unsigned `now` number to a signed number, which is safe because the plausible range of `now` is known to be low, and everything from then on is signed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a pair of variables in order to store your given date:

```
uint256 numOfSecondsAfter1970;
uint256 numOfSecondsBefore1970;
```

Then, suppose you want to know how many seconds have elapsed since your given date:

```
let numOfSeconds = now - numOfSecondsAfter1970 + numOfSecondsBefore1970;
```

If you want to convert `numOfSeconds` into a "standard" date, then you can use [Solidity Time Units](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/units-and-global-variables.html#time-units).

P.S.:

The other answer also works fine (I believe).

The answer here suggests a "purely-unsigned" implementation.

I think that generally, it may be a little "risky" to mix signed integers into unsigned arithmetic, i.e., one needs to consider every operation (arithmetic as well as bit-wise) very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a recommendation to store dates as numbers of seconds since unix epoch 1970-01-01. It is stored like that in the block header out of convinience, it is the same format used for other blockchains.

If your data requires to represet other values I'd suggest to use a better representation, for example you can start with this library
https://github.com/pipermerriam/ethereum-datetime and change the origin from 1970 to some other arbitrary year like 1900 or 1600.